# Minecraft WallMap with Zoomed out MAPS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hey guys I was trying to do a wall map on Minecraft; however, the center map was already zoomed out (by placing it in the cartography-table and adding 1 paper), as a result, I got a map showing some biomes as well as the house.

Then, I tried:

Taking the center-map and walked to one of its edges, right into the square where the arrow became a dot, then I made a new map for that area, but when I put the map in the cartography table and it zoomed out, it turned the same zoomed out map I had. It was not shifted at all even tho I had built it at a point outside the original map.

Is there no way to make a map wall with zoomed out maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Mapping) (emphasis mine):

> The map does not center on the player when created, rather, **the world is broken up into large invisible grid squares, and the map displays the area of whichever grid square it is in when it is first used.** [...] **To make a map that is not identical to the first one, the player would have to move outside of the edges of the first map** (because then they would be in a new grid square). This way, no two maps of the same size can ever partially overlap and every map can display only a fixed area.

The catch here is that your second map is a different size to the your first, so only walking a short distance (i.e. just outside the boundary) means that the center of your second map overlaps with the area of your first, once you expand it.

[This table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Zoom_details) shows the area that each map size covers. In your case, a base zoom size covers a 128 x 128 block area (or 4 chunks). Zoom 1 covers a 256 x 256 area (or 16 chunks). So in order to match up the borders and allow for the expansion of your maps, you will need to accommodate for that extra boundary.

You can use the hotkey <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> on some keyboards) to show chunk borders to count the chunks before you use your map.

Ultimately, when playing with map sizes that are anything other than the base level, or max level zoom, it can be tricky to coordinate the borders to match up.
Locator maps can help you better achieve this, although you may still run into difficulties.